# Autostart spring app

Tags: java, spring

So is there a way to initialize and start a command line Spring app without writing a main method. It seems like all such main methods have the same form

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext ctx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("context.xml", Boot.class);
    FooService fooService = (FooService) ctx.getBean("fooService");
    fooService.bar();
}
```

I suppose that's not complicated, but has someone found a way to provide a way to just specify the `context.xml` at the command line or, better yet, in a manifest file?

The goal here is to simplify the creation of spring applications as executable jars. I hope that I can specify some utility class as the `Main-Class` in the manifest. I suppose I would also need to specify the starting point for the app, a bean and a method on it where begins the process.

Comment: You just did... It might help if you explained what you are trying to accomplish. Do you need a way to package Spring applications as executable jars?

Comment: Yeah, the goal is an executable jar.

Comment: OK, but obviously you could just change your above code to use args[0] instead of "context.xml". It seems like you might be trying to find a generic way of auto-packaging *any* Spring application as an executable jar. My point is that I'm still not sure what you want. Can you add more detail?

Comment: I thought this URL was helpful in answering this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4787719/spring-console-application-configured-using-annotations

Answer (score 6):

I'll try to answer the question as I understand it:

> How to package a jar containing a spring configuration such as I just need to use `java -jar myjar.jar`?

The code snippet you have in your question simply works. You don't have to parameterise the `context.xml`. You just need to bundle your code and its dependencies (spring, etc.) in a single jar with a proper manifest entry for the main class in a jar file.

I personaly use [maven 2](http://maven.apache.org) and here is a [pom.xml](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html) I would use that do just that:

```
<project>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.stackoverflow</groupId>
  <artifactId>stackoverflow-autostart-spring-app</artifactId>
  <version>0.1</version>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <archive>
            <manifest>
              <mainClass>com.stackoverflow.spring.autostart.Autostart</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

This is assuming some package name for the java code, the source code being in the `src/main/java` directory and the file `context.xml` in the `src/main/resources` directory.

So in this `pom.xml` there are several important points:

1. the spring dependency (speaks for itself I believe)
2. the configuration of the [maven jar plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/), that adds the main class as a manifest entry
3. the [maven shade plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/), which is the plugin responsible for gathering all the dependencies/classes and packaging them into one single jar.

The executable jar will be available at `target\stackoverflow-autostart-spring-app-0.1.jar` when running `mvn package`.

<strike>I have this code all working on my box but just realised that I can't attach a zip file here. Anyone know of place I could do so and link here?</strike>

I created a [git repository at github](http://github.com/sleberrigaud/sof) with the code related to this question if you want to check it out.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you so much putting your sample application up on github. I was trying to step through all this configuration and was so close but it wasn't working. I was able to use your skeleton and get up and running. MUCH APPRECIATED!

Answer (score 3):

Yes. Write a simple `SpringMain` which takes an arbitrary number of `xml` and `properties` files as the arguments. You can then (in the main method) initialize an application from these files. Starting your program is then simply a matter of:

```
java -cp myapp.jar util.SpringMain context.xml
```

You then use the lifecycle attributes (`init-method`) on your relevant beans to kick-start the application